# How can I disable RewriteRule for one subcategory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess in my root of website that looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.pl [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([a-z0-9_-]+)\.mydomain\.pl [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php?run=places/%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/upload/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/javascript/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?runit=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But when I type:

> mydomain.pl/guests

I would like to go normally to actual folder guests. I understand that I need to somehow disable this rule for guests subfolder, but how do I do this?

EDIT:

I've included whole .htaccess file

Comment: +1 This is a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've put a htaccess in subfolder and added RewriteEngine Off  and it works.

Comment: This wont work, if the rewrite happens in the folder above.

Comment: Not good solution. If the subfolder contains a foreign application which itself uses an .htaccess and overwrites it on every update, one has to modify it everytime.

Comment: There is an solution without RewriteCond: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1848579/1854856

Answer (score 0):

Add one of these

```
RewriteEngine On

#If the request starts with guests, then pass it through
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^guests
RewriteRule ^ - [L,QSA]

#Or, if the request contains an existing filename or directory, pass it through
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Depends on where are the rules placed. Is it htaccess or main configuration files? Also, are those all your rules?

Comment: @Vinko - Thank you for answer I've included my whole htaccess file. How to change it so it will work?

Comment: When I type http://mydomain.pl/guests i'm redirected to http://mydomain.pl/guests/?runit=guests and I wanted to go to mydomain.pl/guests/ normally (load index.php from inside)

Comment: So it works, but it appends the query string? Then do not use QSA