# mod_rewrite Problem - Routing pages to query string

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I need help with my **mod_rewrite** for a site im currently working on.

Let's say I have this site http://example.com

And I want to be able to make any value after the / to route to page.php like below

```
http://example.com/value1

http://example.com/value2
```

to point to

```
http://example.com/page.php?id=value1

http://example.com/page.php?id=value2
```

,respectively.

But, not route to that page when im pointing to "admin"

```
http://example.com/admin/
```

I've tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(admin)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But it isn't working. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

`$1` is not available at the time of the Condition. I believe what you are looking for is close to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

this rule causes everything not starting with `admin/` to go to `/page.php`. I don't believe the %{param} is optional. Using `RewriteBase /` means you do not to have prepend `/` on `/admin` and `/page.php`; it may actually fault if you use `/page.php` instead of `page.php`

If you have means of accessing the server values, then the final rule can be:

```
RewriteRule . page.php [L]
```

You can find the called url in the `REQUEST_URI`

Comment: just noticed you were correct in the $1, the rule is processed first then conditions checked after. They may refer to the results of the reg-ex

Answer (score 0):

This of any help?

[.htaccess mod_rewrite - how to exclude directory from rewrite rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848500/htaccess-mod-rewrite-how-to-exclude-directory-from-rewrite-rule)