# force pages to end in a slash and rewrite the url

Tags: .htaccess

i have to call my pages in this way:

```
http://example.com/index.php?page=homepage
```

i want to always show the url in this way

```
http://example.com/homepage
```

and at the same time i also want to prevent the insertion of the / at the end of the url...so:

```
http://example.com/homepage/ or http://example.com/homepage
```

point to the same page.
how can i do this trick with htacces? have i to correct all relative path of files in my html?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# activate Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On
# do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [R=301,L,QSA]
# rewrite all other requests to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(css|js)/(.*)?$ $1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R]
```

Last update from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848500/htaccess-mod-rewrite-how-to-exclude-directory-from-rewrite-rule).

Comment: i had to add RewriteBase /example.com/ to make it work, thanks. but now when i call every css or js, they're just replaced with the content of the page. how can i avoid it?

Comment: @1uc4 do you have your js and css on the same folder as your pages? I would assume not

Comment: @leon yes, now it works perfectly when i call example.com/homepage. but when i call example.com/homepage/ everything is searched in example.com/homepage/css or example.com/homepage/js

Comment: @1uc4 trying again - pls check