# Redirect all but one file to secure site using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a secure site, and am currently redirecting visitors to it if they access through the unsecured http://. I am doing that like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I need one file, domain.com/example.php to not ever be redirected to the secure site, and just keep the user there. Can anyone suggest a way of doing this? I've looked at similar code, but I can't work out what needs to be changed to work exactly

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an additional RewriteCond to filter out your URI:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/example.php
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

see [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Answer (score 0):

This previous SO answer will help:  [.htaccess mod_rewrite - how to exclude directory from rewrite rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848500/htaccess-mod-rewrite-how-to-exclude-directory-from-rewrite-rule)

Basically, you'll need a rewrite rule above the existing rules that "rewrites" your desired URLs to themselves.