# exclude images folder from redirect rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have set up in my .htacces file so that anyone trying to visit the site gets redirected to index.html, which is an under construction page. I have an image on there, that doesnt display cos the link gets redirected to index.html, how do i exclude the image from the rule, the path is `/images/underConstruction.png.`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [R=301]
```

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848500/htaccess-mod-rewrite-how-to-exclude-directory-from-rewrite-rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a exclusion condition to your rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/images/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add this line

```
RewriteRule ^images/ - [L]
```

Comment: if i put it below last line dont work, if i put it above last line, its a redirect loop