# mod_rewrite breaking link hrefs

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When using mod_rewrite, I'd like to know if there is a possible, flexible way to globally set the current working directory as root, so stylesheet/image paths won't break when passing parameters via mod_rewrite:

I currently use `define("PATH", "/subfolder/");` of which I place at the beginning of each link href/src, but I'm thinking there has to be a more flexible way of doing this.

EX:

stylesheets/styles.css works when no parameter is being passed, but breaks when a mod_rewrite parameter is in use.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: What do your rewrite rules look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two `RewriteCond` rules here exclude URLs that match a file or folder that physically exists.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or [by adding explicit exclude rules to your mod_rewrite directives.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1848579/1064767)