# Apache mod_rewrite conditions

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mod-rewrite, multiple-conditions

i've got a problem using apaches module rewrite (browser friendly urls). I want to rewrite each request to an specified php document expecting any request containing a given string:

```
RewriteBase /folder/directory/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

How to include a condition to redirect requests including "teststring" (ignoring pre and post text) to another directory? I want to redirect jQuery ajax calls to another directory directly!

---

**Finally got the solution:** [.htaccess mod_rewrite - how to exclude directory from rewrite rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848500/htaccess-mod-rewrite-how-to-exclude-directory-from-rewrite-rule)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what exactly you want. But here's my take on it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)teststring(.*) newdirectory [R,L]
```