# Redirecting to 404 error while accessing directory on web server

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect the user to 404 error file while they try to access directories in my server such as imgs, js, css.

**One Way**
I can put index.html to all those directories with 404 error.

*Cons*

I don't want to do this because their are alot of directories and sub-directories in my server.

**Second Way**
Create a 404.html file and redirect every directory url toward it.
How to acheive this this using .htaccess re-write rule?

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/30334

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1848500

Answer (score 0):

> Create a 404.html file and redirect every directory url toward it. How to acheive this this using .htaccess re-write rule?

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```