# .htaccess excluding directory issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website consisting of a single index.html file. I have several menus, and need to go 3 levels deep, so I want a php-like structure as such: `index.html?main=$1&secondary=$2&tertiary=&3`. This has to be reduced to `www.example.com/$1/$2/$3`. Overall pretty simple I would think, using following rules for in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$  index.html?main=$1&secondary=$2&tertiary=$3
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$  index.html?main=$1&secondary=$2
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$  index.html?main=$1
```

Now, I also have several folders in my root folder that shouldn't be affected, otherwise my include's wont work. Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1848579/1319187) I've already tried exluding these folders using `RewriteRule ^(bower_components|photos)($|/) - [L]` before the other rules, but it didn't work. I've also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17613938/1319187), making a `.htaccess` with contens `RewriteEngine Off` and putting it in my folders, also without success. So obviously I'm doing something wrong somewhere. To show my folder layout, here's a quick snapshot of it:

[image: Folder Layout]

Here's my current `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .*  - [L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$  index.html?main=$1&secondary=$2&tertiary=$3
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$  index.html?main=$1&secondary=$2
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$  index.html?main=$1
```

Now, if I go to `http://localhost/myProject/activities`, so 1 level deep as the `index.html` file is located in `myProject`, it does work and all includes are included correctly. However, when going to `http://localhost/myProject/activities/test`, I get to the basic `index.html` page, but my includes point to `http://localhost/myProject/activities/bower_components/platform/platform.js`, so the `activities` is too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myProject/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .*  - [L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.html?main=$1&secondary=$2&tertiary=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.html?main=$1&secondary=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.html?main=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then for css/js/image inclusion just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

You can also try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/myProject/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: Using `<base href="/myProject/" />` seems to do the trick nicely! Prefer this over rewriting all the links. Thanks!