# htaccess rewrite rule except folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, directory

I have this rule in my `htaccess`

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|bmp|swf|css|html)$ public/index.php [QSA,L]
```

And now I want to add one or two exception folder. Can anyone help? Really appreciate.

Comment: Exact Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848500/htaccess-mod-rewrite-how-to-exclude-directory-from-rewrite-rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a new `RewriteCond` for creating exceptions for 2 folders:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(folder1|folder2)/ [NC]
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|bmp|swf|css|html)$ public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Is this more kind than turn off the engine?

Comment: Turning off the rewrite engine will require you to create a .htaccess in each and every folder in your exception list and here you can do all that from root .htaccess