# How do I exclude stylesheet and javascript files from my rewrite rules?

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule currently as shown below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $2.php?locale=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) $2.php?page=$3&locale=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My page URLs are like this:

```
http://example.com/en/new
```

or this:

```
http://example.com/en/new/1
```

As for the index page it's like this:

```
http://example.com/en/index
```

and I wanna get rid of the 'index' word so I added this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php/$1 [L]
```

Which works as expected except for my web assets (css, js files) which are located under: /css and /js folders now has 500 error. So my question is how to I exclude URLs pointing to these files under these 2 directories from being rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem. Either use the suggested answer from here

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848500/htaccess-mod-rewrite-how-to-exclude-directory-from-rewrite-rule?rq=1
```

or simply create a .htaccess file inside the directory where you don't want rewriting to take place and put this in:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```