# htaccess redirect rule should not apply on 2nd level link

Tags: .htaccess

I have this rule in my htaccess file

Redirect 301 /directory/myfolder /myfolder

it obviously redirects all links with /directory/myfolder to /myfolder even I try to access **/directory/myfolder/another_folder**

I want to apply few exception like it **should not redirect** these links

**/directory/myfolder/another_folder1**

**/directory/myfolder/another_folder2**

**/directory/myfolder/another_folder3**

Thanks

Comment: `Redirect` does not allow any conditional logic. You will need to use mod_rewrite rules (`RewriteRule`). Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848500/htaccess-mod-rewrite-how-to-exclude-directory-from-rewrite-rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **RedirectMatch**

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/dir/myfolder$ /myfolder
```

Comment: Thanks :) this is what I was looking for