# .htaccess mod_rewrite - block symfony login "/(admin|login)"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I want to allow access to /admin and /login only from certain IP addresses (two 192.168.0.1, 10.10.10.1). I already learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848500/htaccess-mod-rewrite-how-to-exclude-directory-from-rewrite-rule#comment-55766606) that I have to use something like `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\..*$`, but how to do this more precise in my example?

I use Symfony2 and have a quite basic htaccess file in my /www folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} calculator.ipsum.de$
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.0\.1$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^10\.10\.10\.1$
RewriteRule (admin|login)/?$ - [F]
```

This should give a 403 - Forbidden for attempts to access that page from IPs other than the ones in the conditions.

Comment: Can I also have a 404 - I want to hide the login?

Comment: Changing the flag from `[F]` to `[R=404,L]` should work

Comment: Where in my file do I have to put the snipped. I tried it as the first rule beyond "On" but it  seem not to work. Can SSL or virtual hosts be a problem?

Comment: That's where I'd recommend to put it. Are you sure you're coming in on those addresses? Does the rule work on its own without the conditions?

Comment: Hm, I think it is not. How can I "test" routing in Apache and debug mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Symfony's [access control](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html)  instead. So in your `app/config/security.yml`, add:

```
security:
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER_IP, ips: [192.168.0.1, 10.10.10.1] }
        - { path: ^/login, roles: ROLE_USER_IP, ips: [192.168.0.1, 10.10.10.1] }
```

That should allow `192.168.0.1` and `10.10.10.1` access to the pages, while blocking anything else.

Alternatively, if you want to do this on the server instead of in your application, you could use Apache's [mod_access module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html) instead of rewriting:

```
<Location "/admin">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from 192.168.0.1 10.10.10.1
    Deny from All
</Location>

<Location "/login">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from 192.168.0.1 10.10.10.1
    Deny from All
</Location>
```

Comment: [I tried the symfony approach, but couldn't get it to work. If I use access control it interfierce with my firewall, resulting in a loop!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690284/symfony-2-allow-login-only-from-whitelisted-ips)