# Separate site under Symfony 1.4 project

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have website running under Symfony 1.4 framework. I created directory in /web called "blog" and uploaded there Wordpress CMS. How can I prevent Sf 1.4 to not route this directory and allow to run Wordpress site?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848500/htaccess-mod-rewrite-how-to-exclude-directory-from-rewrite-rule

Comment: In addition, you'll need to make sure you have the correct .htaccess file in the /blog directory to make sure wordpress works correctly.