# exclude rewrite rule on folder for mvc

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following in my `.htaccess`, it rewrites all to a central file,
I want to bypass it for a certain folder (& all its subfolders), the folder I want to bypass is named "admin" , how should I modify this rewrite to stop rewriting for admin folder?

I checked this question but wasn't able to get the needed results:

[.htaccess mod_rewrite - how to exclude directory from rewrite rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848500/htaccess-mod-rewrite-how-to-exclude-directory-from-rewrite-rule)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest way is to put an .htaccess in the admin folder with nothing but: `RewriteEngine Off`.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude the admin folder from Your rule ,you can use :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```