# URLs Get redirected to root for webroot files

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cakephp

I have a CakePHP app that has some html static files in `webroot`.
HTML files are in some directories like `webroot/dir1/dir2/page.html`. 
When I enter url: `site.com/dir1` I get redirected to `site.com/webroot/dir1/` but when I enter `site.com/dir1/` I get redirected to the first page `site.com`
And If I enter url for the html file: `site.com/dir1/dir2/page.html` I get redirected to the first page `site.com`. It supposed to show the html file. How can I make it show html file and not redirect to first page?

In my public_html the htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

In the webroot the htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: And what's the question? Your post should contain (at least) one question. Please see - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @user1315357 I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely not connected to CakePHP. Just ignore your directory / ies that should not be processed by CakePHP's routing system, see this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848500/htaccess-mod-rewrite-how-to-exclude-directory-from-rewrite-rule).

Insert `.htaccess` into your directory/ies that should be ignored:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

Comment: in all of them and subdirectories?

Comment: You don't have to, `.htaccess` works hierarchically, it will be enough in parent repository.

Comment: Added the htaccess. still not working. Address is still processed by cakephp

Comment: It seems like a mess. What is your `public_html` directory, where it comes from? Is this a directory where are placed your directories with static content? If so, place .htaccess file into this directory. If it is not, you should provide more information about your directory structure.

Comment: Its in a cpanel with a home directory and public_html subdirectory of home. the webroot dir is in public_html and static files folder in the webroot directory
home >public_html >webroot>static_dir1>static_dir2>static_dir3>page.html

Answer (score 0):

your questions isn't about php, 
it's about the apache Webserver or more about -> [Apache Module mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Rewrite Engine is only called one time, so you have to put all changes in one File.

kind regards
set